# find the last record or last row in a table using sql query

Tags: database, oracle

how to find last record OR LAST ROW NOT Using WHERE CLAUSE..
I WANT TO USE ROWNUM ..

```
Name      AGE     SURNAME
A          23     S
B          34     Y
C          45     O
D          43     P
```

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You need a column to specify the ordering, if you want to define one particular row as the "last" one.

Answer (score 0):

As it was commented by others, you need to define which is the order criteria to do that. Here is my suggestion:

```
select x.*
from (
       select t.*,
              row_number() over(order by <fieldname> desc) as rn
       from table t
      ) x
where x.rn = 1
```

Comment: Ok, it's fixed... and by the way, next time, don't freak out, sometimes people format code a little different than you...